# Grails Plugin Config Excluded

Tags: grails

I have some values from a plugin's `Config.groovy` that I wanted incorporated as part of the main Application. However, it seems that they're excluded, according to the docs.

How can I define values in a plugin and have those values propagated to the main app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- define a configuration file that is not excluded in `src/groovy`. eg. `MyPluginConfig.groovy` and merge it in in the `doWithSpring` and `onConfigChange` closures in your plugin's definition class. This method is outlined in [this blog post](http://swestfall.blogspot.com/2011/08/grails-plugins-and-default-configs.html).
- use your plugin's `_Install.groovy` script to manually write your configuration into the host application's `Config.groovy`. This method is evident in the `S2Quickstart` script from the [Spring Security Core plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/scripts/S2Quickstart.groovy).
- Use the [Plugin Config plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/plugin-config). This plugin handles these situations very nicely.

Comment: Very helpful info.  I think I will take the 1st option.  Quick question - there are 3 steps in the blog post.  Do steps 2 and 3 get placed in the plugin, or the main app?  Thanks.

Comment: Those are in the plugin's descriptor class: `ExampleGrailsPlugin.groovy`